# Installing cunit on Ubuntu Quantal

Tags: 12.10, apt, package-management, 64-bit

I'm trying to install the cunit (C unit testing framework) packages on Quantal (64bit). cunit seems to be held in a number of packages, but according to `apt-get` these are broken.

Attempt 1:

```
$ sudo apt-get -f install libcunit1-*
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libcunit1-ncurses' for regex 'libcunit1-*'
Note, selecting 'libcunit1-dev' for regex 'libcunit1-*'
Note, selecting 'libcunit1-doc' for regex 'libcunit1-*'
Note, selecting 'libcunit1' for regex 'libcunit1-*'
Note, selecting 'libcunit1-ncurses-dev' for regex 'libcunit1-*'
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 libcunit1-ncurses : Conflicts: libcunit1 but 2.1-0.dfsg-10 is to be installed
 libcunit1-ncurses-dev : Conflicts: libcunit1-dev but 2.1-0.dfsg-10 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Attempt 2:

```
$ sudo apt-get -f install 2.1-0.dfsg-10
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package 2.1-0.dfsg-10
E: Couldn't find any package by regex '2.1-0.dfsg-10'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Try looking for the packages in synaptic. (Which can be easily installed from the software center)

Comment: Le sigh. I hate `synaptic`, however, I had a go since you suggested it and `synaptic` decided that it was only the `ncurses` packages that were problematic and the rest can be installed. So, thanks for  the suggestion. I'll delete this question in a few minutes, unless you want to add your comment as an actual answer?

Comment: If my suggestion helped, I'll add it as an answer. You never know if someone might get the same problem.

Comment: Why do you hate synaptic? (If I may ask?)

Comment: Well, partly because it is slower than using the command line (for me at least) and it lacks some basic UI features. For example, I cannot easily select a bunch of different packages at once and mark them for installation; I have to select each one in turn and mark them individually. Basically, I'm lazy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try synaptic (which can be easily installed from the software center) to check if the necessary packages can be installed/are available.

Comment: Thanks. Synaptic figured out that it was the ncurses packages that were broken, so this should work on the command line: `sudo apt-get install libcunit1 libcunit1-doc libcunit1-dev`